# how to store last 3 random number in 3 different variables javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a Ludo game and my condition is if there are three 6 in a row then the user's chance will be passed to the next user. I made a random number from 1 to 6. I was storing the last digit with a variable called lastDice and compared the last one with a recent random number but I can not get the idea of the last 3 random numbers to compare. **But the condition is if the last 3 random numbers are 6s(6,6,6) then the game must stop**. Codes are as follows:

```js
const playing = true;
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
const lastDice = 0;

if (playing) {
  if (random === 6 && lastDice === 6) {
    document.getElementById('score--1').textContent = 0; // update the ui
  } else {
    nextPlayer(); // its a function to call the next player
  }

  lastDice = dice; // storing the last random number for comparing next random number
}
```

Comment: Have you considered building a "history" array of all dice rolls? (Or just the last 3, if you have no use for older rolls)

Comment: I have no use for older rolls.

Comment: Agree with @DBS, store them in an array, if you only want the last 3, put the latest at the top of the array and remove the last element then get a random number between 0 and 2 to get a random dice role out of array

Comment: The array is the only way to compare the numbers? or is there any way?

Comment: Rather than working at a solution work for your requirement. Why 
you need last 3 digits for? If it is for finding whether user got 3 consecutive 6s then you don't need an array. Keep adding the result of draw to a variable. When you reach 18 you know it's time to stop. Or tell us why you need results of draw or what kind of comparison.

Comment: I don't need an array and I never said I need one. people are giving the solution with array . I just want if the random number generates three(3) 6s(6,6,6) in a row then the game should stop. otherwise, everything will work as before.

Comment: Then check for draw count reaches 3 & sum is 18. It's done

Comment: I need to count the draw(click) and compare the value of the random numbers if it's 18. right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple array, and use `Math.random` to get the index of the number to pick:

```
var lastNums = [0, 0, 0];   // 3rd last, 2nd last, and last number
var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
var chosenNumber = lastNums[index];
// then compare
```

If you want to remove the first number and replace it with a new dice roll, simply use:

```
lastNums.shift();  // remove the 3rd last number
lastNums.push(lastDice);  // add the current dice roll
```

Edit: If handling arrays are a bit too complex for you, here's another method using three variables:

```
// create 3 number variables
// I'll give the variables a non-zero value first
var firstNum = 1;
var secondNum = 2;
var thirdNum = 3;

// shuffle the number variables after each turn 
// to set lastDice as previous dice roll

// here I treat firstNum as the last dice roll, 
// secondNum as the second last dice roll, 
// and thirdNum as the third last dice roll
thirdNum = secondNum;
secondNum = firstNum;
firstNum = lastDice;
```

Example: I rolled a 4. After each turn, when the numbers are shuffled, thirdNum gets replaced with secondNum, secondNum gets replaced with firstNum, firstNum gets replaced with lastDice. So I should have: firstNum = 4, secondNum = 1, thirdNum = 2.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to not using the array?

Comment: You can create three different variables and shuffle the values too. I'll edit this post later.

Comment: bro, I don't need to shuffle the numbers. cause  I can generate numbers with a random function(Math.random). I just need to compare the first 3 random numbers with each other.

Comment: I guess, I solved the problem. I added the random number to an array and used a condition if the array is more than 3 first index of the array will be removed. and then I compared the indexing value of an array with each other to see if all their value is equally 6. like the following code:  const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1); container.push(random); if(container.length >3){
            container.shift(); };if(container[0] === 6 && container[1] === 6 && container[2] === 6){
            scores[activePlayer] = 0}

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I solved the problem. I added the random number to an array and used a condition if the array is more than 3 first index of the array will be removed. and then I compared the indexing value of an array with each other to see if all their value is equally 6. like the following code:

```js
const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
      // container is an empty array called before
        container.push(random);
        //remove if conditon full fills
        if(container.length >3){
            container.shift();
        };
        console.log(container);
        if(container[0] === 6 && container[1] === 6 && container[2] === 6){
            scores[activePlayer] = 0;
            document.getElementById('score--'+activePlayer).textContent = 0;
            switchPlayer();
        };
```